# What is ORBX.js

Tags: javascript, html

What is ORBX.js and how does it relate to the following points I thought were only available on a operating system (Not Web, but actually running in the system):

- Watching a 1080p video without codecs
- Playing a game (Like Left 4 Dead 2) on the Web
- What characteristics does it offer for the web that we are used to seeing on a non web system (With this i mean running an app that is not web related, like a computer game)
- How is this possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a non-critical "this is super awesome" piece for those who have not yet heard of this technology, see this write-up: [Today I saw the future](https://brendaneich.com/2013/05/today-i-saw-the-future/) (this is the same as mentioned by Jonathan in the comment above - and yes, its kind of a puff piece)

To digest it, this is the latest re-emergence of the concept of the thin-client. In short, the viewing device uses a web browser to launch a "stream" that is very much like a virtual/remote desktop. It specifically allows remote desktop applications itself, but it also allows something where the behind-the-scenes implementation is different; this is the "GPU cloud" referred to.

What makes this a thing is that it would effectively allow future computers/devices to target one stationary target - the ability to run a web browser and decode a video stream, and if they can do that then they can just as well any application or program imaginable, no matter how intensive it might be. This is because all the processing would be done in the cloud, with the only thing sent to the client being a video stream. In theory this could extend consumer hardware cycles and cut prices, as a 1ghz CPU would be just as good as a 100ghz.

In reality, the obstacles are bandwidth, latency, connectivity, and of course a successful implementation of this technology with wide-spread marketplace compatibility. Then, of course, you start having to pay for cloud computing as a cost of using your cloud-based applications. And without a fast internet connection, you are back to using native downloaded apps only.

For now there is no open encoder, which is a problem for developers and programmers. Only time will tell if it is a viable technology.